# HttpContext.Current.Response.Filter will Replace wrong strings

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm using HttpContext.Current.Response.Filter in HttpModule to replace some strings on my pages.

```
public class RplModule : IHttpModule
{
    public void Init(HttpApplication app)
    {
        app.BeginRequest += new EventHandler(context_ReleaseRequestState);
    }

    public void context_ReleaseRequestState(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       HttpContext.Current.Response.Filter = new HtmlFilter(HttpContext.Current.Response.Filter);
    }
    public void Dispose() { }
}
```

and here is HtmlFilter Class:

```
public class  HtmlFilter : MemoryStream
{
    private readonly Stream _outputStream;
    public  HtmlFilter(Stream outputStream)
    {
        _outputStream = outputStream;
    }

    public override void Write(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
    {
        var contentInBuffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer);
        contentInBuffer = contentInBuffer.Replace("href=\"Res", "href=\"User/Res");
        _outputStream.Write(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(contentInBuffer), offset, Encoding.UTF8.GetByteCount(contentInBuffer));
        _outputStream.Flush();
    }
}
```

It works fine and will replace every occurrence, But the problem is that it will break some lines and some texts and codes will be mixed up and the page can not be load well. Sometimes it will add some strange string in some places too!
Where is the problem?

Comment: this Write method may be called multiple times for a single page. Recall that the HttpWriter object chunks together data and then writes it to its output stream. Each time the HttpWriter sends out a chunk of data your response filter's Write method is invoked.

Comment: can you write a piece of code please?

Comment: I am assuming for "break some lines and some texts and codes will be mixed up" that you should try with regex exact replace and match for better output. My assumption is that text like "href=resources" is also get replaced and you do want this to replace. If am i wrong then please specify the problem with actual example.

Comment: It will change some strange parts which is not related to strings I want to replace. for example it will change "</div" into "</radi> v" and it will move some text to wrong places which is very very strange!!!